# fortify scan showing different scanned file counts for every trigger

Tags: fortify

I have executed a fortify scan on a directory and found that every time I trigger the scan the scanned file count is different. My fortify sca commands are in a jenkins job.

Appreciate your help!

1. cd directory
2. sourceanalyzer -b  -clean
3. sourceanalyzer -cp jars -autoheap  @exclude files -b buildid @include files  -debug -verbose -logfile log_file_name -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=directory
4. sourceanalyzer -autoheap -64 -b buildid -scan -f fprfilename -debug -verbose -logfile filename -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=dir